# jpa lazy return all element

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have two class Brand and Model. I use lazy loading.

```
@Entity
public class Brand {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long brandId;

  private String brand;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "brand")
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<Model> modelList;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Model {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long modelId;

  private String model;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "brandId")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Brand brand;
  ...
}
```

In my repository i use standard method findAll.

```
public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long>
```

When i do a call to get Brand

curl http://localhost:8080/brands

I get also model

[
   {
      "brandId":1,
      "brand":"Toyota",
      "modelList":[
         {
            "modelId":1,
            "model":"Echo"
         },
         {
            "modelId":2,
            "model":"Corolla"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "brandId":2,
      "brand":"Honda",
      "modelList":[
         {
            "modelId":3,
            "model":"Civic"
         },
         {
            "modelId":4,
            "model":"Accord"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "brandId":3,
      "brand":"Kia",
      "modelList":[
         {
            "modelId":5,
            "model":"Sorento"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "brandId":4,
      "brand":"Ford",
      "modelList":[
         {
            "modelId":6,
            "model":"Mustang"
         }
      ]
   }
]

Are there something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to omit models from `Brand`, you should put `@JsonBackReference` on `modelList` instead of `@JsonManagedReference`.

`@JsonManagedReference` is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally.

`@JsonBackReference` is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That work,  @@JsonBackReference in  Brand class,  @@JsonManagedReference in model class